# Why select tag is not updating when opening a modal?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, materialize

I have a modal as directive. The problem is that when I'm triying to open the modal with data already filled the select tags won't update till the second time that I open modal.

I'm using angular and [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) . Please note that all the other fields work but the selects doesn't until second time i open modal but in the log always shows the data of scope updated so the problem is that select is not rendering on time or something like that.

**JS that opens the modal with filled data**

```
$scope.update = function (customer) {
    console.log("selected type id: "+$scope.selectedIdType)

    $scope.isUpdating = true;
    updateView()
    $scope.newCustomer = customer;
    var resultSplitTin = customer.tin.split('-');
    $scope.inputId = resultSplitTin[1] + (resultSplitTin.length > 2 ? '-' + resultSplitTin[2] : '');
    $scope.selectedIdType = resultSplitTin[0];
    console.log($scope.inputId)
    $scope.inputPhone = customer.phones[0];
    $scope.newCustomer.zone = customer.zone;
    console.log("selected type id after: "+$scope.selectedIdType)

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.zones.length; i++) {
       // console.log(customer.zone + " == " + $scope.zones[i].code);
        if (customer.zone == $scope.zones[i].code) {
            $scope.newCustomer.zone = $scope.zones[i];
        }
    }


    $('#modalCustomer').openModal();
    $('#selectedTaxInput').material_select();
    $('#selectedZoneInput').material_select();
    $('#selectedIdInput').material_select();


};
```

**Modal HTML (all inputs update but no the selects)**

```
<form class="col s12" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <select id="selectedIdInput" ng-options="id for id in idTypes" ng-model="selectedIdType">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Elije una opci&oacute;n</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Tipo</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s8">
                    <input id="identification" type="text" class="validate" ng-class="{'valid': inputId.length > 0}"
                           ng-model="inputId">
                    <label for="identification"
                           ng-class="{'active': inputId.length > 0}">Identificaci&oacute;n</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="name" type="text" class="validate" ng-class="{'valid': newCustomer.name.length > 0}"
                       ng-model="newCustomer.name">
                <label for="name" ng-class="{'active': newCustomer.name.length > 0}">Nombre</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="telephone" type="text" class="validate" ng-class="{'valid': inputPhone.length > 0}"
                       ng-model="inputPhone">
                <label for="telephone" ng-class="{'active': inputPhone.length > 0}">Tel&eacute;fono</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12" >
                <textarea id="address" class="materialize-textarea"
                          ng-class="{'valid': newCustomer.address.length > 0}"
                          ng-model="newCustomer.address"></textarea>
                <label for="address" ng-class="{'active': newCustomer.address.length > 0}">Direcci&oacute;n</label>
            </div>

            <label style="margin-left:10px">Localidad</label>

            <div id="selectedZone" class="input-field col s12 l12" input-field>
                <select id="selectedZoneInput" ng-model="newCustomer.zone"
                        ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in zones track by item.code"
                        ng-change="showSelected()" watch>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Elije una opci&oacute;n</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**FIX**

```
$scope.update = function (customer) {
    console.log("selected type id: "+$scope.selectedIdType)

    $scope.isUpdating = true;
    updateView()
    $scope.newCustomer = customer;
    var resultSplitTin = customer.tin.split('-');
    $scope.inputId = resultSplitTin[1] + (resultSplitTin.length > 2 ? '-' + resultSplitTin[2] : '');
    $scope.selectedIdType = resultSplitTin[0];
    console.log($scope.inputId)
    $scope.inputPhone = customer.phones[0];
    $scope.newCustomer.zone = customer.zone;
    console.log("selected type id after: "+$scope.selectedIdType)

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.zones.length; i++) {
       // console.log(customer.zone + " == " + $scope.zones[i].code);
        if (customer.zone == $scope.zones[i].code) {
            $scope.newCustomer.zone = $scope.zones[i];
        }
    }


    $('#modalCustomer').openModal({
        ready: function(){
            $timeout(function() {
                $('#selectedTaxInput').material_select();
                $('#selectedZoneInput').material_select();
                $('#selectedIdInput').material_select();
            });
        }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using jQuery to open the modal and binding the values so the Angular is unaware of the changes. There is a concept of [digest cycle](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angular%20digest%20cycle) due to which Angular updates the view when model value changes and vice-versa.

But here, you are using jQuery to modify data in Angular context so you need to manually tell Angular that something has changed. You can use this by calling `$scope.$apply()` but it has some limitation i.e. it may fail and throw an exception if the digest cycle is already in progress.

So you can make use of `$timeout` service.

```
$('#modalCustomer').openModal();

// Assuming this selector is the modal's selector
$('#modalCustomer').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $('#selectedTaxInput').material_select();
        $('#selectedZoneInput').material_select();
        $('#selectedIdInput').material_select();
    });
});
```

Comment: hello i tryed that and didn't seems to work, also i tryed :  $scope.$apply(); asking before for $scope.$root.$$phase but it didn't work

Comment: Yeah it does the same thing

Comment: i implemented what you just told me but with the materialize event when modal is ready and then pass the $timeout in controller definition thanx a lot !!!!!